# How to diff custom file list with WinMerge

Tags: svn, diff, winmerge

I have a code directory structure, which is this:

```
  modudle1
    trunk
      pom.xml
    branches
      1.1
        pom.xml
  modudle2
    trunk
      pom.xml
      submodule-2.1
        pom.xml
      submodule-2.2
        pom.xml
    branches
      1.1
        pom.xml
        submodule-2.1
          pom.xml
        submodule-2.2
          pom.xml
```

I need to compare pom.xml files in trunk folders with the ones in branches/1.1:

```
  modudle1\trunk\pom.xml 
  modudle1\branches\1.1\pom.xml 

  modudle2\trunk\pom.xml
  modudle2\branches\1.1\pom.xml

  modudle2\trunk\submodule-2.1\pom.xml
  modudle2\branches\1.1\submodule-2.1\pom.xml

  modudle2\trunk\submodule-2.2\pom.xml
  modudle2\branches\1.1\submodule-2.2\pom.xml
```

What solutions are available to do this? Is there a solution to use with WinMerge, where I could present a filelist to compare? Other suggestions and tools are welcome, too.

Answer (score 3):

[Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/) has the ***Synchronize Dirs*** command (In the ***Commands*** Menu) that allows you to compare 2 folders recursivelly and to see what are the differencese (what files are in one directory and not in the other, what files have changed).

Unfortunatelly you cannot generate a "global diff" file with the result of this comparison (or if you can, I am yet to find how).

Give it a try and tell me if this was what you were looking for.

Comment: WinMerge has the functionality to compare 2 folders, too. But as you can see in the example above - the structure implies that there are no such 2 folders comparing which would show the differences between all the pom.xml files.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the simplest way would be to script it, in order to pass to WinMerge:

- one fixed file
- one file found by the script (which is essentially a '`find . -name "pom.xml"`' in the right paths.

In short, I don't know about a diff tool taking one file, and a list of files to compare that one file to.